# Upload python package to Azure DevOps custom artifactory without using using username/password in the pypirc file

Tags: python, azure-devops, token, artifacts, twine

My challenge is to publish a python package to a feed (Azure DevOps / Artifacts) using Authentification by Token.

Let me share what I tried :

**A** - [Build pipeline] I build a python package without a problem. Then I obtain an artifact to publish :

*A.1* : The obtained artifact :

[image]

*A.2* : The content of .pypirc file :

```
[distutils]
Index-servers =
  py-test

[py-test]
Repository = http://AZURE_DEVOPS_URL/_packaging/py-test/pypi/upload
```

**B** - [Release pipeline]

Before creating the release pipeline :

*B.1* In artifacts, I have created a new feed named py-test

*B.2* I created a service connexion using Authentification Token to connect to the repository (specified in the .pypirc file)

[image]

*B.3* Now, how I specified my release pipeline ?

My release pipeline takes the artifact produced by the build pipline and executes these steps :

*B.3.1* Twine authentificate

[image]

*B.3.2* twine upload

The complete command is :

```
twine upload -r py-test --config-file=dist/.pypirc dist/*
```

Now when I run the release pipeline, I get this :

[image]

Logs :

[image]

the log message :

```
2023-07-20T12:17:00.7581410Z ##[section]Starting: Upload the package to the acrtifactory
2023-07-20T12:17:00.7751611Z ==============================================================================
2023-07-20T12:17:00.7751900Z Task         : Command line
2023-07-20T12:17:00.7751977Z Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
2023-07-20T12:17:00.7752075Z Version      : 2.201.1
2023-07-20T12:17:00.7752159Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-07-20T12:17:00.7752216Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
2023-07-20T12:17:00.7752301Z ==============================================================================
2023-07-20T12:17:01.7494177Z Generating script.
2023-07-20T12:17:01.7588823Z Script contents: shell
2023-07-20T12:17:01.7594609Z twine upload -r py-test --config-file=dist/.pypirc dist/*
2023-07-20T12:17:01.7888075Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2023-07-20T12:17:01.8089352Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "C:\DevopsAgents\LocalAgent\_work\_temp\f871e3b1-0997-4b62-a24f-8f72a4ca9cf5.cmd""
2023-07-20T12:17:02.3709133Z Uploading distributions to 
2023-07-20T12:17:02.3710981Z http://AZURE_DEVOPS_URL/_packaging/py-test/pypi/upload
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4192345Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4192724Z   File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4192959Z   File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4193174Z   File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python311\Scripts\twine.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4197266Z   File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\twine\__main__.py", line 33, in main
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4199690Z     error = cli.dispatch(sys.argv[1:])
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4200307Z             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4200503Z   File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\twine\cli.py", line 123, in dispatch
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4223403Z     return main(args.args)
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4224634Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4225268Z   File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\twine\commands\upload.py", line 198, in main
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4226650Z     return upload(upload_settings, parsed_args.dists)
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4226823Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4227033Z   File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\twine\commands\upload.py", line 127, in upload
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4227260Z     repository = upload_settings.create_repository()
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4227431Z                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4227642Z   File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\twine\settings.py", line 329, in create_repository
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4227840Z     self.username,
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4227984Z     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4228181Z   File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\twine\settings.py", line 131, in username
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4228404Z     return cast(Optional[str], self.auth.username)
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4228564Z                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4228843Z   File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\twine\auth.py", line 34, in username
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4229044Z     return utils.get_userpass_value(
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4229276Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4229514Z   File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\twine\utils.py", line 248, in get_userpass_value
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4229750Z     value = prompt_strategy()
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4229914Z             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4230121Z   File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\twine\auth.py", line 85, in username_from_keyring_or_prompt
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4230353Z     return self.prompt("username", input)
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4231715Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4231926Z   File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\twine\auth.py", line 96, in prompt
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4232290Z     return how(f"Enter your {what}: ")
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4232453Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-07-20T12:17:02.4232617Z EOFError: EOF when reading a line
2023-07-20T12:17:02.5155575Z ##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
2023-07-20T12:17:02.5514398Z ##[section]Finishing: Upload the package to the acrtifactory
```

When I see this, I don't understand why the twine authentificate is not enough, why should I submit username/password?

Question : How can I make my release pipeline working with the Token Authentification to avoid displaying my username/password in pypirc?

Thanks in advance for your help!